# creating new column based on existing column using a dictionary for a Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Hellow Stack Overflow community,

I have a `df` which has a column called "native_country". However, I would like to make a new column which groups the countries into continents. For example, China would be grouped with all of the countries belonging to Aisa. The code is shown below,

First I make a `ContinentDict` that holds the country/continents,

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 'Cambodia':'Asia', 'Hong':'Asia', 
                   'India':'Asia', 'Japan':'Asia', 'Laos':'Asia', 
                   'Philippines':'Asia',
                   'South':'Asia', 'Taiwan':'Asia', 'Thailand':'Asia', 
                   'Vietnam':'Asia', 'Canada':'Canada', 'United States':'United 
                    States',
                   'Cuba':'Caribbean', 'Dominican-Republic':'Caribbean', 
                   'Haiti':'Caribbean', 'Jamaica':'Caribbean', 
                   'Trinadad&Tobago':'Caribbean',
                   'England':'Europe', 'France':'Europe', 'Germany':'Europe', 
                   'Greece':'Europe', 'Holand-Netherlands':'Europe', 
                   'Hungary':'Europe',
                   'Ireland':'Europe', 'Italy':'Europe', 'Poland':'Europe', 
                   'Portugal':'Europe', 'Scotland':'Europe', 
                   'Yugoslavia':'Europe',
                   'Columbia':'Latin America', 'Ecuador':'Latin America', 
                   'El-Salvador':'Latin America', 'Guatemala':'Latin America',
                   'Honduras':'Latin America', 'Nicaragua':'Latin America', 
                   'Peru':'Latin America', 'Mexico':'Mexico', '?':'Unknown', 
                   'Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc)':'US Territories', 'Puerto-
                   Rico':'US Territories'}
```

Next, I assgin the continents to the df

`df = df.assign(continent=df['native_country'].map(ContinentDict))`

However, the `continents` column is filled with NaN's. Does anyone know why? Is there something I am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'native_country': ContinentDict.keys()})
df = df.assign(continent=df['native_country'].map(ContinentDict))
>>> df.head()
       native_country      continent
0              Canada         Canada
1            Honduras  Latin America
2                Hong           Asia
3  Dominican-Republic      Caribbean
4               Italy         Europe

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['continent'], df['native_country']])
>>> midx
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Asia', u'Canada', u'Caribbean', u'Europe', u'Latin America', u'Mexico', u'US Territories', u'United States', u'Unknown'], [u'?', u'Cambodia', u'Canada', u'China', u'Columbia', u'Cuba', u'Dominican-Republic', u'Ecuador', u'El-Salvador', u'England', u'France', u'Germany', u'Greece', u'Guatemala', u'Haiti', u'Holand-Netherlands', u'Honduras', u'Hong', u'Hungary', u'India', u'Ireland', u'Italy', u'Jamaica', u'Japan', u'Laos', u'Mexico', u'Nicaragua', u'Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc)', u'Peru', u'Philippines', u'Poland', u'Portugal', u'Puerto-Rico', u'Scotland', u'South', u'Taiwan', u'Thailand', u'Trinadad&Tobago', u'United States', u'Vietnam', u'Yugoslavia']],
           labels=[[1, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 7, 4, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 0, 6, 4, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 8], [2, 16, 17, 6, 21, 28, 25, 27, 29, 18, 33, 40, 1, 10, 38, 7, 39, 20, 24, 4, 36, 34, 22, 9, 31, 5, 8, 14, 19, 32, 13, 3, 15, 37, 12, 23, 35, 11, 26, 30, 0]],
           names=[u'continent', u'native_country'])
```

Once you have country and continent in the dataframe, you could just set the index:

```
df = df.assign(data=1)
>>> df.set_index(['continent', 'native_country']).sort_index()
                                           data
continent      native_country                  
Asia           Cambodia                       1
               China                          1
               Hong                           1
               India                          1
               Japan                          1
               Laos                           1
               Philippines                    1
               South                          1
               Taiwan                         1
               Thailand                       1
               Vietnam                        1
Canada         Canada                         1
Caribbean      Cuba                           1
               Dominican-Republic             1
               Haiti                          1
               Jamaica                        1
               Trinadad&Tobago                1
Europe         England                        1
               France                         1
               Germany                        1
               Greece                         1
               Holand-Netherlands             1
               Hungary                        1
               Ireland                        1
               Italy                          1
               Poland                         1
               Portugal                       1
               Scotland                       1
               Yugoslavia                     1
Latin America  Columbia                       1
               Ecuador                        1
               El-Salvador                    1
               Guatemala                      1
               Honduras                       1
               Nicaragua                      1
               Peru                           1
Mexico         Mexico                         1
US Territories Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc)     1
               Puerto-Rico                    1
United States  United States                  1
Unknown        ?                              1
```

Comment: Thanks! @Alexander, I am now stuck on adding the df with native_country and continent with the rest of my original df. Would i just simply merge the two together?

Comment: The columns in my original df are as follows: age, workclass, fnlwgt, education, education_num, marital_status, occupation, relationship, race, sex, capital_gain, capital_loss, hours_per_week, native_country, and income_binary. I want to add the df with the continents with the original df with all the variables stated above. @Alexander

Comment: It sounds like you just want to add the continent as a new column to your existing dataframe.  `df = df.assign(continent=df['native_country'].map(ContinentDict))` should do that.  The issue then is if you have rows with multiple rows.  You would then need to aggregate them somehow (e.g. sum, max, mean, etc) via `groupby`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. make a new column that holds the continents. I added that single line of code `df.assign(continent=df['native_country'].map(ContinentDict))`. However, it gives me all NaN's. Is this the issue you are talking about where I would need to aggregate them?? @Alexander

Comment: Are there any spaces or other white space in the `native_country` column.  You could clean it via:  `df['native_country'] = df['native_country'].str.strip()`.

Comment: I don't believe there are but I tried running `df['native_country'] = df['native_country'].str.strip()` and got the following error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` @Alexander

Comment: So you have some missing values.  You can first try: `df['native_country'].fillna('?')`

Comment: Gotcha, I renamed the '?' to 'unknown' instead of 'NA'. It worked for some for some of the continents. For example `Caribbean`, `Asia`, `mexico`,  and `Europe`. But all of the other `continents` seem to still be `NaN`. Could these be the `continents` in which have the missing values?  @Alexander

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154494/discussion-between-alexander-and-t-mcwilliams).

Answer (score 0):

```
df.iloc[df['native_country'].map(ContinentDict).argsort()]
```